# manual swing data binding

Tags: java, swing, design-patterns, data-binding

I have rather big swing interface (several textboxes, comboboxes, checkboxes, custom popup dialogs etc) and a data model that has to be changed when ui control changes: new text is entered into text box, check box is clicked, etc.

The question is: what is the best practice to organize update+validation of input values.

Unfortunately I can not use binding framework like beansbinding.

Answer (score 2):

Add appropriate listeners to the components, and update the model when the events are fired.

Or design your UI so that everything is saved to the model only when a *Save* or *OK* button is clicked. This also helps with validation, because you just need to validate everything at once, when the button is clicked.

Comment: +1 `you just need to validate everything at once, when the button`

Comment: I've been doing swing this way, and I always felt like I was the stupid one for doing it manually; so +1. I would also like to add that you shouldn't rely on beans binding. Last I checked it was as dead of a project as could be. Looking at their issues page: http://java.net/jira/browse/BEANSBINDING#selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.project%3Aissues-panel I'd say its in about the same state.

Answer (score 2):

Combine the answer of JB Nizet with validation in your components, for example by using `JFormattedTextField` (or an enhanced version of this). You can use the `JFormattedTextField` also as editor for `JComboBox` instances. You can add validation to `JSlider` instances.

In short, provide immediate feedback to the user when he types in an invalid value. That combined with validation on the model side makes a good application.

This can be compared to a modern website: client-side validation with javascript to give the user immediate feedback + server-side validation for validation which does not go through the UI, or to avoid nasty users bypassing your client-side validation